# Jasmine and requireJs - Mismatched anonymous define() module:

Tags: javascript, requirejs, jasmine

I am trying to use `Jasmine`.js test with `requires`.

**Here's part of my specRunner**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $rootRequirejs?>/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require.config({
        baseUrl: "./"
    });
</script>
```

**Here's part of my spec file**

```
define([

], function () {

});
```

**When I run my specRunner I get the following error, why?**

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function () {

}
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch require.js:7
P require.js:7
A require.js:19
(anonymous function)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try this way to load your spec files using require.js

```
<script 
     data-main="./yourSpec" 
     src="<?php echo $rootRequirejs?>/require.js"
>
</script>
```